# Android Return Cursor

Tags: java, android

```
public Cursor DB_GetUnitPrice(){
    DataBaseHelper myDbHelper = new DataBaseHelper(this.getApplicationContext());
    myDbHelper = new DataBaseHelper(this);
    try { 
    myDbHelper.createDataBase();  
    } catch (IOException ioe) { 
    throw new Error("Unable to create database"); 
    }  
    try {  
    myDbHelper.openDataBase();         
    }catch(SQLException sqle){  
    throw sqle;  
    }

    try {  
    SQLiteDatabase db = myDbHelper.getReadableDatabase();

    String Insert_Data="Select Normal_Rate,Discounted_Rate FROM Tbl_Rate WHERE Route_ID="+global.Route_ID+" AND ((From_LocationID="+global.From_LocationID+" AND To_LocationID="+global.To_LocationID+") OR (From_LocationID="+global.To_LocationID+" AND To_LocationID="+global.From_LocationID + "))";
    Cursor c = db.rawQuery(Insert_Data, null);

    //c.close(); // cannot will error
    //db.close(); // cannot will error
    //myDbHelper.close();
        return c;
    }catch(Exception e){  
    Log.d("DB_GetUnitPrice",e.getMessage());
    }
    return null;
}
```

This is how i return the `Cursor` , but the problem is i can't close the `c.close();`, because because close the cursor connection, will occur error. how to close cursor connection before return the function value?

this is the error:-

```
    06-02 03:19:23.084: D/AndroidRuntime(6864): Shutting down VM
06-02 03:19:23.084: W/dalvikvm(6864): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40b3d1f8)
06-02 03:19:23.089: E/AndroidRuntime(6864): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
06-02 03:19:23.089: E/AndroidRuntime(6864): java.lang.IllegalStateException: attempt to re-open an already-closed object: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteQuery (mSql = Select Normal_Rate,Discounted_Rate FROM Tbl_Rate WHERE Route_ID=1 AND ((From_LocationID=1 AND To_LocationID=10) OR (From_LocationID=10 AND To_LocationID=1))) 
06-02 03:19:23.089: E/AndroidRuntime(6864):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteClosable.acquireReference(SQLiteClosable.java:33)
06-02 03:19:23.089: E/AndroidRuntime(6864):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteQuery.fillWindow(SQLiteQuery.java:82)
06-02 03:19:23.089: E/AndroidRuntime(6864):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteCursor.fillWindow(SQLiteCursor.java:164)
06-02 03:19:23.089: E/AndroidRuntime(6864):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteCursor.getCount(SQLiteCursor.java:156)
06-02 03:19:23.089: E/AndroidRuntime(6864):     at android.database.AbstractCursor.moveToPosition(AbstractCursor.java:161)
06-02 03:19:23.089: E/AndroidRuntime(6864):     at android.database.AbstractCursor.moveToNext(AbstractCursor.java:209)
06-02 03:19:23.089: E/AndroidRuntime(6864):     at com.example.abc2.MainActivity.CheckUnitPrice(MainActivity.java:1794)
06-02 03:19:23.089: E/AndroidRuntime(6864):     at com.example.abc2.MainActivity$3.onClick(MainActivity.java:543)
06-02 03:19:23.089: E/AndroidRuntime(6864):     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:3511)
06-02 03:19:23.089: E/AndroidRuntime(6864):     at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:14105)
06-02 03:19:23.089: E/AndroidRuntime(6864):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:605)
06-02 03:19:23.089: E/AndroidRuntime(6864):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
06-02 03:19:23.089: E/AndroidRuntime(6864):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
06-02 03:19:23.089: E/AndroidRuntime(6864):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4424)
06-02 03:19:23.089: E/AndroidRuntime(6864):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
06-02 03:19:23.089: E/AndroidRuntime(6864):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
06-02 03:19:23.089: E/AndroidRuntime(6864):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:784)
06-02 03:19:23.089: E/AndroidRuntime(6864):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:551)
06-02 03:19:23.089: E/AndroidRuntime(6864):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Sample Answer from  `Giru Bhai`

`Cursor c = DB_GetUnitPrice();
c.close();`

is this correct way?

Comment: Close the cursor after using DB_GetButtonList because you return cursor itself.

Comment: @Giru Bhai look at my updated answer, is that way are correct?

Comment: After viewing log,the error is not at cursor,Its saying attempt to re-open an already-closed object

Comment: @GiruBhai But after didn't use the `c.close();`, then no error occur. why?

Comment: `how to close cursor connection before return the function value?`. Do you mean to close cursor before returning DB_GetUnitPrice() function? if yes, why don't you try this way `Cursor c = null; try {  
    SQLiteDatabase db = ...
    c = db.rawQuery(Insert_Data, null);
    }catch(Exception e){  
    Log.d("DB_GetUnitPrice",e.getMessage());
    } finally {if(null != c) {try{c.close();} catch(Exception e1){}}}`

Comment: @User1211111 same error with my question

Comment: Ok guess your question is not related closing cursor, it is related to the error log. Based on log it Looks like you are reopening the closed object. Can you please give us some more error log.?

Comment: @User1211111 updated, please have a look

Comment: Can you tell me what are you doing in CheckUnitPrice() method? I suspect some thing wrong in this method.

Answer (score 1):

From the Android docs.

```
close()

Closes the Cursor, releasing all of its resources and making it completely invalid
```

Your call to `return c;` after you have closed it is likely causing the error

May be try something like this.

```
Cursor c = DB_GetUnitPrice();
```

use this cursor object then close the cursor as

```
c.close();
```

For more info about Cursor see this link [Android Cursor](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/Cursor.html)

**Edit**
You cannot reopen closed object as you are trying to getting  cursor after closing it,so you have got the error

Comment: Please explain the error message? how come this error occur?

Comment: this is not an answer